# How to remove the selected option in select tag?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a dropdown in such a way that on click of a button new dropdown is created but it should not show the selected option of the previous dropdown. I am able to create the dropdowns on button click but I can't figure out how to not show selected options of previous dropdowns.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an Array and map all your dropdowns from that. And in onClick function of button simply pop or modify the array element. I hope you got it. Feel feel to ask doubts and for more please update the source code.